# "Car sale" vs "Cars sale"

Tags: nouns, attributive-nouns

I have always thought that the latter: **Cars sale**, is incorrect; yet Google returns almost the same number of results for both!

My concern is about **Rule extraction** and **Rules extraction** to be precise; for a Chapter title!

P.S. Clearly, we are selling many cars (or extracting many rules); not one!

Comment: Google return results isn't always a good metric. When I checked, many of the hits for `cars sale` point to websites that say "USED CARS FOR SALE".

Comment: If you're confident enough in your ability to write a book, you shouldn't need us to tell you what you want to say.

Comment: If you have a toy car based on the movie "Cars," it's a "Cars car."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your examples, *car* and *rule* are [noun adjuncts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct): nouns used as adjectives. Wikipedia notes:

> Noun adjuncts were traditionally mostly singular (e.g. "trouser press") except when there were lexical restrictions (e.g. "arms race"), but there is a recent trend towards more use of plural ones, especially in UK English. Many of these can also be and/or were originally interpreted and spelled as plural possessives....

*Car sale* and *rule extraction* are both traditionally correct. *Rules extraction* fits the recent trend, but *cars sale* would be problematic: *cars' sale* (the selling of cars) doesn't mean the same thing as *car sale* (a discount on cars).

Answer (score 0):

Car Sales seems the more correct term, unless speaking of the sale of a particular car. Cars sale seems more like a typo than anything else.