# Which is the correct form: "Parameter set", "parameters set", or "parameters' set"?

Tags: mathematics, attributive-nouns

I have sets of parameters like `(1, 2, 3, 5)` or `(3.14, 2.73, 1.44, 1.73)`. They are named, but I do not think it makes any difference. Which  form is the correct one to call one general case or example of such things?

1. Parameter set.
2. Parameters set.
3. Parameters' set.

I would opt for choice 2. but I am not really sure. That would impose the plural so maybe choice 1 is correct.  Choice 3 sounds really off to me in English, but that would be the direct calque from my native language.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119873/car-sale-vs-cars-sale

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct form would be *parameter set*.

Consider the forms in which *set* can be applied to objects: when you have *a set of pencils*, the alternative is *pencil set*, never *pencils set*. You'd never see 2. used, except in some strange circumstances, e.g. *scissors set*, where the word used to refer to one object in the set is plural.

3 is incorrect, because the set doesn't belong to the parameters. *Parameters' set* would, in some cases, be correct, but not here. An example that comes to mind is where you might refer to a few parameters, then identify the set they belong to with e.g. *the aforementioned parameters' set*.

Comment: So my hunch was good. Thank you +1 and accept for coming up with a valid example for every case. I would imagine 2. would be correct in cases like `((p1 = 1, p2 = 2), (p1 = 0.5, p2 = 3.13) )`, then it would be set of sets of parameters, so maybe one could call it a `parameters set` although I find it quite murky.

Comment: Also see the Wikipedia article on [noun adjuncts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct) for discussion of the underlying rule and its exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

(1, 2, 3, 5) is one parameter set.
(1, 2, 3, 5) and (3.14, 2.73, 1.44, 1.73) are two parameter sets.

(1, 2, 3, 5) is a set of parameters.
(1, 2, 3, 5) and (3.14, 2.73, 1.44, 1.73) are two sets of parameters.

Details:

(1, 2, 3, 5) is one parameter set. *Parameter* describes what kind of set.

(1, 2, 3, 5) is a set of parameters. *Parameters* is plural because it refers to what's in the set. If the set contains more than one parameter, the contents of that set are described in plural form.

Comment: To express the answer from @user49891 in another way: In "set of parameters", *parameter* is a noun and takes the plural form; in "parameter set", *parameter* is an adjective, and in English adjectives to **not** take plural forms.